# Expressão "nada a ver" ou "nada haver" - qual a forma correcta?

Tags: gramática, expressões

É visto normalmente nas redes sociais as expressões "nada a ver" e "nada haver" sendo utilizadas constantemente. Qual é a forma correta quando quer expressar que algo não faz sentido? "Nada a ver" ou "nada haver"?

Questão relacionada: *["Tem a ver" — Qual é a origem desta expressão?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/851/)*

Comment: O correto é "nada a ver". Vou ver se consigo elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: É extraordinário a quantidade de livros onde aparece *nada haver* em vez de *nada a ver*.

Comment: Orion nenhuma resposta o satisfez? Porquê?

Answer (score 24):

O correto é "nada a ver".

"Nada haver" não faz sentido, porque "haver", neste caso estrito, dentre os significados, pode significar "existir" ou "estar na posse de", então não tem como aplicar o "haver" no contexto, sem modificar ou adicionar algo na expressão e sem mudar o sentido.

A expressão "nada a ver" seria algo como "nada a ter com", ou melhor, "não há relação alguma".

Comment: Finalmente uma resposta a essa pergunta que por tantos anos me atrapalha!!!! Obrigado!

Comment: Não é o perguntado, mas sabendo que "a haver" significa "devido", **pode-se** dizer "nada a haver" com o significado de "nada é devido".

Comment: Além disso: "É um problema nada haver (=não haver nada) num raio de 30 Km"

Answer (score 17):

A expressão **nada haver** está incorreta, pois apesar de [*nada*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/nada) poder ser utilizado como advérbio (exp.: *nada tem*), o verbo [haver](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/haver) ou é utilizado juntamente com outro verbo (exp.: *vai haver*, *deve haver*), ou simplesmente substitui o uso do verbo *ocorrer* (exp.: *está a haver uma festa*). Logo, nunca teria o significado de **nada existe**, pois [haver e existir têm aplicações diferentes](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/haverexistir/3409).

Porém existe uma forma correta de utilizar *nada* e *haver* na mesma expressão:

- *O João **nada tem a haver** à Maria*: pode por exemplo significar que o João não se deve sentir forçado a retribuir o favor à Maria.

A expressão **nada a ver**, por outro lado está corretíssima, significando que *não **existe** nada para ver* ou, com outro significado, que determinado objecto/situação *não tem relação nenhuma* com outro:

- *Isto **não tem nada a ver** com aquilo*: pode por exemplo significar que determinado aspeto (ou coisa) não se deve comparar com outro(a).
- *Aqui **não há nada a ver***: pode por exemplo transmitir que determinado local não tem nenhuma particularidade para ser observada.

Deixo por último a [explicação da porto editora](http://www.portoeditora.pt/espacolinguaportuguesa/duvidas-da-lingua-portuguesa/detalhe-duvidas-lp/ver/ter-a-ver-ou-ter-a-haver-?id=5491&langid=1):

### ter a ver ou ter a haver?

> As duas formas são corretas, mas têm sentidos diferentes.
>
> **Ter a ver** com, ou **ter que ver** com, tem o sentido de «estar relacionado com» ou «dizer respeito a»:
>
> - O texto tem a ver com política.
>
> **Ter a haver** quer dizer «ter a receber»:
>
> - O cliente tem a haver 2 euros de troco.

Comment: Armfoot, da primeira vez que li isto no ano passado ou isso nem reparei: ***nada haver*** é possível, não tem é nada a ver com sentido pedido na pergunta; podes dizer «apesar de *nada haver* a recear», «ele afirma *nada haver* feito», etc.

Answer (score 4):

Tem a ver ou tem haver?
A ver e haver são termos homófonos e também são parônimas, ou seja, possuem formas semelhantes porém sentidos diferentes.

Publicado por: Sabrina Vilarinho em Dúvidas de vocabulário

Isto não tem nada haver ou a ver com você!

Você já ficou com dúvidas entre qual utilizar?

O problema tem acontecido porque “haver” e “a ver” são parônimas, ou seja, apresentam sentido diferente, mas têm formas semelhantes. Ao passo que são homófonas, pois produzem o mesmo som!

Antes se dizia: Isso não tem nada que ver com você! Contudo, foi-se simplificando ainda mais com a substituição pela preposição “a”. Incorporamos o modo francês de se falar, o que parece ser um caso de eufonia, a fim de tornar o som mais agradável, mais facilitado.

Por isso, quando quiser dizer que algo não tem relação a outro, use “a ver”.

O verbo “haver” surge quando alguém precisa receber dinheiro de alguém ou recuperar algo que perdeu: Preciso haver meu dinheiro.

Use “ter a haver” no sentido de “ter a receber”.

Compare: Ana tem tudo a ver com as coisas que aconteceram. (As coisas que aconteceram têm relação com Ana).

Ana não tem nada a haver. (Ana não tem nada para receber de ninguém).

Comment: Anderson, gostei da referência, podias linkar o site original do post que citaste?

Comment: @gmauch Vai ser difícil dizer qual é o original, data a quantidade de reproduções desse texto na internet.

Comment: @gmauch http://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/gramatica/tem-ver-ou-tem-haver.htm

Answer (score -1):

"Nada haver" no sentido de "não tem nenhuma relação", ou "é completamente despropositado" é uma monstruosidade, uma hipercorreção absurda. A origem parece ser, "pessoas inteligentes/bem informadas/cultas usam a letra "h" nas mais diversas posições, sem que eu entenda bem por quê; portanto, lá vou eu espalhar "agás" a torto e a direito, para ver se pareço sabido". Em outras palavras, "nada haver" não tem nada a ver.