# "Tem a ver" -- Qual é a origem desta expressão?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas, origem-histórica

*Ter a ver com* significa como sabemos *estar relacionado com*:

> As marés têm a ver com a gravidade do sol e da lua.
>
> A origem do agradecimento japonês *arigato* não tem nada a ver com o equivalente português *obrigado.*

Contudo não é nada óbvio como é que o significado de **tem a ver** resulta do significado das palavras individuais **tem, a** e **ver**. Alguém sabe como é que a expressão se formou?

Esta demanda é agora uma empresa internacional. Questões relacionadas: [***avoir à voir*** em francês](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16499/quelle-est-l-origine-de-l-expression-avoir-%C3%A0-voir) e [***tener que ver*** em espanhol](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15282/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-del-modismo-tener-que-ver-con).

**ENGLISH**

What is the origin of the phrase ***ter a ver***?

***Ter a ver com*** (literally *to have to see with*, meaning *to have to do with*) mean, as everybody knows, to have some relation with:

> The tides have to do (têm a ver) with the gravity of the sun and the moon.
>
> The origin of the Japanese word *arigato* (thank you) has nothing to do (não tem nada a ver) with the Portuguese equivalent *obrigado*

It is however not obvious at all how the meaning of ***ter a ver*** emerges from the meaning of the individual words ***ter, a*** and ***ver***. Does anyone know how the phrase came to be?

This quest is now an international enterprise. Related questions: [***avoir à voir*** in French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16499/quelle-est-l-origine-de-l-expression-avoir-%C3%A0-voir) e [***tener que ver*** in Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15282/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-origen-del-modismo-tener-que-ver-con).

Comment: Quer dizer que isto é mito? *"O português deu várias palavras ao idioma japonês: obrigado (arigato), botão (botan), vaca (waca), cadeira (kantera), vidro (bidro)."* - [fonte](https://pt-pt.facebook.com/notes/jadetravel-histórias-e-viagens/depois-de-vasco-da-gama-o-homem-ficou-maior-e-o-mundo-menor/267121123398537)

Comment: @brasofilo Há muitas [palavras japonesas de origem portuguesa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palavras_japonesas_de_origem_portuguesa), mas parece que _arigato_ não é uma delas.

Comment: Até hoje acreditava fielmente nessas origem... o número de silabas confere e a fonética parece similar... mesmo que não seja assim, imagino em 1500, num porto japonês, visitantes e nativos se divertindo: arigato! obrigado! arigatooo! obrigadooo!

Comment: @brasofilo Pois, também eu acreditei. Até que uma japonesa me disse o contrário. As palavras japonesas de origem portuguesa parecem ser sobretudo nomes de coisas que os portugueses lá introduziram. Por isso, a "vaca" também me parece suspeita. Os japoneses já deveriam ter um nome para as vacas deles.

Comment: Pois é, estive olhando e isso de Waca parece bem suspeito também... teve alguém que deu uma boa trolada com isso, jjj

Comment: @brasofilo Pois, sabes, o pessoal entusiasma-se. Sabe que há palavras japonesas de origem portuguesa, e depois leva tudo à frente: qualquer palavra japonesa parecida com o equivalente português tem de ser de origem portuguesa!

Comment: You can translate "tem a ver com" as "is related to", as is to express correlation between two things. "ver", in portuguese, integrates a lot of expressions with many different meanings and often subtle ones. Is a good start point on your quest to check it out the verb "ver". A good example is "ver" meaning "to do"  "vou ver isso que você me pediu -> I'll do what you've asked me to". PT_BR.

Comment: ter a ver is: have to do with.

Comment: @Lambie, foi isso mesmo que eu escrevi.

Answer (score 13):

*Ter a ver* é um galicismo, vide [*avoir à voir*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_%C3%A0_voir).

A expressão portuguesa correspondente é *ter que ver*:

> As marés ***têm que ver*** com a gravidade do Sol e da Lua.

A expressão torna-se assim um pouco mais transparente: *ter (alguma coisa) que (=para) ver*. É uma construção análoga a "temos muito que fazer", "há muito que fazer".

Ainda assim, é difícil perceber o que *ver* significa neste contexto, já que a expressão está tão cristalizada. Mas o verbo correspondente é também usado em espanhol (*tener que ver*) e italiano (*avere a che vedere*). A expressão italiana põe-na [um](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/V/vedere.php) e [outro dicionário](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=vedere%201) sob o significado de "encontrar":

> 3. incontrare: *vedere un amico a teatro* **|lieto di vederla!**, si dice per complimento incontrando qualcuno **|guarda chi si vede!**, (fig., fam.) salutando qualcuno che non ci si aspettava di incontrare **|avere a che vedere**, avere rapporto o relazione: *con loro non ho niente a che vedere*; *il suo comportamento ha a che vedere con quanto è successo*

E o outro:

> 5 estens. Incontrare: *è molto tempo che non vediamo i nostri amici*; *oggi pomeriggio vedrò tuo fratello*; *che piacere vederti!*
>
> - || Avere un rapporto, un contatto personale; far visita a qualcuno
> - **|| Andare a vedere qualcuno**, fargli una visita: *sono andato a vederlo all'ospedale*; *devo andare a v. il mio avvocato*
> - **|| Avere a che vedere con qualcuno, con qualcosa**, averci un rapporto, una relazione, averci qualcosa in comune: *con quella gente non ho niente a che v.*; *anche lui ha a che v. con quella storia*
> - ... (continua)

Comment: Até à preposição _a_ eu consegui chegar: _tenho dois filmes a ver_ . Esbarrei foi precisamente no _ver_: o que é que as marés veem?

Comment: @Jacinto Editei o post com mais alguma informação.

Comment: A tradução do italiano ajudaria muito a entender!!

Comment: @falsarella Eu entendo o italiano muito imperfeitamente. Eles usam _vedere alguém_ com o significado de _econtrar alguém_. Mas não vejo como é que isso ajuda. Já um exemplo no link _avoir à voir_ me dá uma pista que vou incluir no corpo da pergunta.

Comment: @Jacinto encontrei qualquer coisa no ciberduvidas: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ainda-a-volta-do-ter-a-verter-que-verter-a-haver/10951 e a sequela https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/de-novo-o-ter-que-verter-a-verter-a-haver-etc/11157 . Depois incorporo isto na reposta.

Comment: Eu li as coisas do ciberdúvidas. Pelo que eu consegui compreender, eles demonstram que a expressão correta é _ter a ver_ e não _ter a haver_, o que nunca esteve em dúvida aqui, e que o significado de _ter a ver_ não se reduz a uma combinação dos significados individuais de _ter a_ e _ver_, que foi a premissa inicial e razão de ser da minha pergunta. Será que me escapou alguma coisas de relevante para compreender a formação da expressão? Viste a atualização da pergunta?

Comment: @Jacinto Há muitas perguntas sobre "ter a ver". Viste a última, em particular a parte: " Pegando no dicionário de Latim-Francês, de Gaffiot, Hachette, Paris, reli o que se dizia sobre o verbo videre (verbete: video, vidi, visum, ere) e, no ponto 7, pude ler: «A) voir avec les yeux de l’esprit, voir par la pensée, en imagination.»"

Comment: Nunca vi nada a dizer que o correto é *ter a ver*, apenas que *ter que ver* é mais comum significar *ter de ver* (e aliás *ter de ver* veio também do francês, o original é também *ter que ver*, tal como no espanhol).

Comment: @Artefacto Não percebi a intenção do teu último comentário. Li o conteúdo todo dos dois links no teu comentário de ontem. _Ver_ também tem  em português, de acordo com o DACL, todos os sentidos que tu enumeraste nos equivalentes estrangeiros. Mas não tou a ver (com os olhos do espírito) como como é que isso ajuda. _Ter a ver em_ é que me parece ser uma origem possível da expressão, pois tem uma interpretação literal inteligível em certos contextos.

Answer (score 5):

**PORTUGUESE (in English below)**

Apesar do esforço do Artefacto, esta questão vai ter que ficar em aberto, pois continuamos sem saber como *ter a ver com* apareceu. Mas entretanto eu pensei em duas hipóteses especulativas para a origem da expressão, as quais exponho abaixo. A premissa na base de ambas é que *ter a ver com* evoluiu de uma expressão cujo significado resultasse da combinação dos significados literais de *ter, a* e *ver*. Creio que *ter a* não oferece problemas: como explicado na resposta do Artefacto, pode significar *ter que, ter de*, ou *ter para*; por exemplo, *ter que engomar uma camisa* ou *ter uma camisa para engomar* é mais ou menos o mesmo que *ter uma camisa a engomar*. O problema está no *ver*.

Primeira especulação: ***ter a ver com*** evoluiu de ***ter a ver em***. O equivalente em francês, *avoir à voir dans*, é usado. No *Wiktionnaire* o primeiro exemplo na explicação de [avoir à voir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_%C3%A0_voir), ***est-ce que j’ai quelque chose à voir là-dedans?*** pode traduzir-se por ***eu tenho alguma coisa a ver nisso?*** Nalguns contextos, alguém que nunca tivesse ouvido a expressão *ter a ver em* compreendê-la-ia perfeitamente a partir do significado das palavras individuais. Por exemplo se ***a Marta não tem nada a ver na casa da Vera***, não há nada na casa da Vera que diga respeito à Marta, logo, não há relação alguma entre a Marta e casa da Vera. Com o passar do tempo esta expressão poderia passar a ser usada em contextos em que *ver* fosse usado mais metaforicamente. Por exemplo, ***não tenho nada a ver nesse assunto*** ou ***não tenho nada a ver na vida dela***. Nestes exemplos *ver* ainda pode reter algo do seu significado literal, mas fica então aberto o caminho a usos onde *ver* nada tem de literal. Por exemplo, ***o Carlos diz que as melancias dele não cresceram por causa do calor excessivo, mas o calor não tem nada a ver nisso, ele é que não as regou***, ou ***o fraco crescimento das melancias não tem nada a ver no calor.*** Agora só falta substituir *em* por *com*. Isso poderia acontecer por analogia entre *ter a ver em* e *ter relação com*.

Segunda especulação: a expressão foi sempre ***ter a ver com***, mas inicialmente era usada apenas entre duas pessoas e quando havia alguma coisa para os dois realmente verem. Por exemplo, ***o João tem uma casa a ver com a Sara***, mesmo para alguém que nunca tivesse ouvido a expressão *ter a ver com*, significaria que ***o João e a Sara querem (ou têm que) ver juntos uma casa*** por exemplo por terem decidido viver juntos. Isto significa que existe alguma relação entre eles. Com o tempo *ter a ver com* poderia ser usado para situações onde não houvesse necessariamente algo de concreto a ver com os olhos, simplesmente para indicar uma relação qualquer. Por exemplo, ***ó mãe, o Sr. Manel tem alguma coisa a ver com a D. Lena? Sempre que passa à porta dela, bate e fala com ela.*** Aqui poderia ou não haver qualquer coisa a ver literalmente. Mas fica aberto o caminho para usos onde *ver* é impossível, e *ter a ver com* mantém apenas o significado de *ter relação com*, como ***os céticos dizem que o aquecimento global não tem nada a ver com a acumulação de dióxido de carbono na atmosfera.***

Em vária outras línguas existem expressões com o mesmo significado que são traduções literais umas das outras. Em inglês existe *to have something to do with* com o mesmo significado. A expressão poderia evoluir numa língua e o produto acabado, aplicado mesmo em contextos onde *ver* perdeu por completo o significado literal, ser importado pelas outras línguas. Isto parece-me pouco provável. Não estou a ver nós, por exemplo, passarmos a dizer coisas como *as marés têm a ver com a gravidade do sol e da lua* só porque noutra língua se usar a expressão equivalente com o significado de *estar relacionado com*. As expressões nas várias línguas poderiam ter evoluído independentemente (parece-me pouco provável); poderiam ter evoluído paralelamente influenciando-se umas às outras. Ou será que já existia no latim? Mas a questão de como *ver* perdeu o significado literal coloca-se onde quer que a expressão tenha evoluído.

**ENGLISH**

Despite Artefacto’s best efforts, this question remains open, for will still don’t know how *ter a ver com* arose. But in the meantime I’ve thought of two speculative hypotheses, which I explain below. The premise underlying both of them is that *ter a ver com* evolved from a phrase the meaning of which emerges from the combination of the literal meanings of the individual words. I believe *ter a* poses no problems: as Artefacto explains, it mean *to have to* (*ter que, ter de* or *ter para*); for instance, ***ter que*** *engomar uma camisa* (to have to iron a shirt) or ***ter*** *uma camisa* ***para*** *engomar* means the same as ***ter*** *uma camisa* ***a*** *engomar* (to have a shirt to iron). The problem lies in *ver* (see).

First speculation: ***ter a ver com*** (to have to see with) evolved from ***ter a ver em*** (to have to see in). The French equivalent, *avoir à voir dans*, is in current use. In *Wiktionnaire*, the first example of [avoir à voir](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/avoir_%C3%A0_voir), ***est-ce que j’ai quelque chose à voir là-dedans?*** may be translated as ***eu tenho alguma coisa a ver nisso?*** (do I have anything to see in that?). In some contexts, someone who had never heard the phrase *ter a ver em* would understand it perfectly from the meaning of the individual words. For instance, if ***Marta não tem nada a ver na casa da Vera*** (Marta has nothing to see in Vera’s home), there is nothing at Vera’s that concerns Marta, so there’s no relationship between Marta and Vera’s home. With the passing of time, people might start using the phrase in contexts where *ver* (see) is used metaphorically. For instance, ***não tenho nada a ver nesse assunto*** (I have nothing to see in that matter) or ***não tenho nada a ver na vida dela*** (I have nothing to see in her life). In these examples *ver* may retain something of its literal meaning, but it opens the way for purely metaphorical uses of *ver*. For instance, ***Carlos diz que as melancias dele não cresceram por causa do calor excessivo, mas o calor não tem nada a ver nisso, ele é que não as regou*** (Carlos says his watermelons failed to grow because of the excessive heat, but the heat has nothing to see in that, the problem is that he didn’t water them) or ***o fraco crescimento das melancias não tem nada a ver no calor*** (the poor growth of the watermelons has nothing to see in the heat). Now we only have to substitute ***com*** (with) for ***em*** (in). This might happen by analogy between *ter a ver em* (to have to see in) and *ter relação com* (to have a relation with).

Second speculation: the phrase has always been ***ter a ver com*** (to have to see with), but was originally use only between two people when there was something to be seen by them. For instance, ***o João tem uma casa a ver com a Sara***, (João has a house to see with Sara) would mean, even for someone who had never heard *ter a ver com* (have to see with), that João and Sara want (or have) to see a house together, for instance because they decided to live together. If two people have to see something together, there must be some relationship between them. Later people could start using the phrase in situations where there might not be anything to see with the eyes, simply to imply that there is some relationship. For instance, ***ó mãe, o Sr. Manel tem alguma coisa a ver com a D. Lena? Sempre que passa à porta dela, bate e fala com ela*** (mum, Mr. Manel has anything to see with Mrs. Lena? He always knocks at her door and talks to her). Here there might or might not be something to see literally. But the way would be open for other uses where *seeing* is impossible, and *ter a ver com* means *ter relação com* (to have a relation with), as in ***os céticos dizem que o aquecimento global não tem nada a ver com a acumulação de dióxido de carbono na atmosfera*** (sceptics say global warming has nothing to see with the accumulation of carbon dioxide in the athmosphere).

Answer (score 0):

Acho que veio de uma possível afirmação, quando um negócio dependeria do aval de outrem: “Não posso decidir sozinha, vou ver isso com o João. Com João? João não tem nada a ver com isso!”

Comment: Eldio, bem-vindo ao site. É uma hipótese engenhosa. Mas nesse contexto não seria mais natural "Vais ver isso com o João?! O João não tem nada **que ver isso**"?