# "Dias de folga a ver" ou "dias de folga haver"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras

Qual é a forma correta de escrita?

> *Você tem dois dias de folga em **a ver**.*

ou

> *Você tem dois dias de folga em **haver**.*

ou, ainda, nenhuma delas e essa construção está errada?

Comment: Cássio, vê o que eu fiz ao teu título. Se não gostares, podes simplesmente fazer "rollback" ou mudar à tua vontade. A minha ideia foi mostrar logo no título qual era a dúvida.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sabendo que "ter a haver" [significa](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ter%20a%20haver) "ser-lhe devido" ou "receber", a forma correta seria:

> Você tem dois dias de folga **a haver**.

A pergunta [Expressão "nada a ver" ou "nada haver" - qual a forma correcta?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/90/express%c3%a3o-nada-a-ver-ou-nada-haver-qual-a-forma-correcta) tem mais detalhes sobre isto, mas *atenção* que a pergunta é principalmente respondida sobre a expressão «[não tem] nada a ver» (ou seja, «não está relacionado com o que estamos a falar») e não sobre a expressão «ter algo a haver» (ou seja, «ter algo a receber»).

Sugiro a leitura atenta dessa outra pergunta, tendo esta minha ressalva anterior em conta. :)

---

Há ainda outra pergunta relacionada, acerca da expressão "ter que ver" (que soa parecida, mas tem um significado diferente) :
["Tem a ver" -- Qual é a origem desta expressão?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/851/tem-a-ver-qual-%c3%a9-a-origem-desta-express%c3%a3o/977#977)

Comment: Entendido! Obrigado pela resposta.